# How do I get Entity Framework to generate migrations that will work with SQL Server CE?

Tags: entity-framework-6, sql-server-ce

When I add a migration scaffold, it includes commands that do not work with SQL Server CE. For instance the `RenameColumn()` and `RenameIndex()` functions will not execute on SQL Server CE.

Is there a way to set the code generator in `Configuration:DbMigrationsConfiguration` to generate SQL Server CE compatible commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL CE does not support index rename, you could manually add Drop and Create instead: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2442

SQL CE does not support column renames, only table renames